# Copy content from one TD to another with Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, clone

I want to copy the dates from the top `td` and put each one in the corresponding `td` below so I can then style with CSS to put all info on one line. This is coming from a WordPress plugin that I can't change. I currently have this:

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="table-dates">Fri 15</td>
    <td class="table-dates">Fri 16</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class=“table-times”>
      <a href="">9:30pm</a>
      <br>
      <a href="">9:30pm</a>
    </td>
    <td class=“table-times”>
      <a href="">4:30pm</a>
      <br>
      <a href="">6:30pm</a>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

My goal is this below, obviously I'll delete the `td` with `table-dates` class as I'll no longer need them:

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="table-dates">Fri 15</td>
    <td class="table-dates">Fri 16</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class=“table-times”>
      <span>Fri 15</span>
      <a href="">9:30pm</a>
      <br>
      <a href="">9:30pm</a>
    </td>
    <td class=“table-times”>
      <span>Fri 16</span>
      <a href="">4:30pm</a>
      <br>
      <a href="">6:30pm</a>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I just need to know if this possible and what approach I should be looking at to achieve this. Thanks.

Comment: Can you clarify "This is coming from a wordpress plugin that I can't change" - what exactly can't you change?

Comment: Sorry, It's written PHP and all I can get to is the output which is this table. I dont want to display it in a table format so I want to manipulate it with CSS. I need the date and time within the same element so I can output on one line i.e. Fri 16 - 8:30, 9:30 etc...

Comment: use for each for the first table then get the data put that data into next table $('td').each(function(t){console.log($(this).text());}). in that same function you also can use addClass method to add custom style. More calrification required

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using jQuery can be done just like this.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".table-dates").each(function(i,e) {
   var elem = $("<span/>").append($(e).html());
   $("table").find(".table-times")[i].prepend(elem.html());
  });
 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tr>
<td class="table-dates">Fri 15</td>
<td class="table-dates">Fri 16</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="table-times">
<a href="">9:30pm</a>
<br>
<a href="">9:30pm</a>
</td>
<td class="table-times">
<a href="">4:30pm</a>
<br>
<a href="">6:30pm</a>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I noticed that the span in the code does not seem to be outputted around the date text. I added a span in the php and called it from the JQuery... 
 $("table").find(".table-times **.date-span**")[i].prepend(elem.html());

Answer (score 0):

Go to plugins and add a new plugin called custom css and js
then make a new js and add use .table-dates to do whatever you want with jquery

Answer (score 0):

```js
var trlist = $("tr");
var toptd = $(trlist[0]).find("td");
var bottomtd = $(trlist[1]).find("td");

toptd.each(function (idx) {
  var span = $("<span>");
  var td = $(this);
  span.text(td.text());
  $(bottomtd[idx]).prepend(span);
  //console.log(idx);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="table-dates">Fri 15</td>
    <td class="table-dates">Fri 16</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class=“table-times”>
      <a href="">9:30pm</a>
      <br>
      <a href="">9:30pm</a>
    </td>
    <td class=“table-times”>
      <a href="">4:30pm</a>
      <br>
      <a href="">6:30pm</a>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```